# Asp.net Getting values from access database

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to get all the details of a User in an Access database. But i cant seem to save each columns value to a label. Here is the code i am using.
Also UserId has a value assigned to it already

```
  string connString = (@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=DataDirectory|HorseDB.mdb");
  OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connString);
  conn.Open();
  OleDbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
  cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT * FROM [Users] WHERE [UserId] = @UserId ";
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId", UserId);
  OleDbDataReader dbReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
  while (dbReader.Read())
  {
      accountUserIdLabel.Text = dbReader.GetValue(0).ToString();
      //Will add other labels once this works
  }
  dbReader.Close();
  conn.Close();
```

Comment: What problem do you have? Any error? No records returned?

Comment: That looks like it should work.  In what way does it not?

Comment: the label doesn't have the value after it runs

Comment: Are you referencing to the right column? try to eliminate asterisk (*) and write the specific column name like "SELECT Id FROM Users"

Comment: @Cheesy: When you debug this, what value do you get from `dbReader.GetValue()`?  What other values are available?

Comment: Try to use `dbReader[0]` or `dbReader.GetString(0)`

Comment: Step through and check that you are entering the `while` loop. It may be that the `UserId` is not being matched and so zero records are being returned?

Comment: I think i found the problem, The value i assigned to UserId is a Session Variable. When i try to assign the Session variable to the label i get "System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader "

Comment: As I thought. So, you need to store the actual `UserId` (i.e. 7) and then your code should work as you expect. By the sounds of if you are already running a query to get the `UserId` is that correct?

Comment: Sorry for the long delay for the reply, but i eventually found the problem, In the connection string before DataDirectory i forgot a |.